# How to use the -c flag in python

Tags: python

I noticed in the python doc that there is a `-c` flag. Here is what python doc says:

> Execute the Python code in *command*. *command* can be one or more
>   statements separated by newlines, with significant leading whitespace
>   as in normal module code.

There is no example in the doc and I couldn't figure out how to make this work, and also in what situations it may help.

Anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just pass regular Python code as the argument to the flag:

```
python -c 'print 1
print 2'
```

Import modules works, and blank lines are OK, too:

```
python -c '
import pprint
pprint.pprint(1)
'
```

---

When using this feature, just be mindful of shell quoting (and indentation), and keep in mind that if you're using this outside of a few shell scripts, you might be doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I need to quote using ''. Btw, how do I enter a newline?

Comment: @Jason The quotes are needed to prevent your shell from somehow interpreting / messing with your Python code. You enter a newline by pressing enter on your keyboard. Any terminal will input that as a newline if you types a quote first.

Comment: When I press enter it terminates my inputs and starts executing. Does it have anything to do with the platform or version? I'm using a Ubuntu with python 2.7

Comment: @Jason You might have forgotten to type a quote prior to typing enter. If not, please paste your terminal contents here.

Comment: Here is my terminal: `srf10mwu@cru-13gx ~/scripts/tools: python -c 'print 10
Unmatched '.
srf10mwu@cru-13gx ~/scripts/tools: python -c 'print 10'
10
srf10mwu@cru-13gx ~/scripts/tools:`

Comment: `Unmatched '.` is what the terminal gives me. Just to clarify my previous comment.

Comment: @Jason Something might be wrong with your terminal / shell, but it's a bit difficult to pinpoint what from here : /

Comment: @Thomas Orozco: It might be the shell issue. I tested in bash and it works. But tcsh won't. But either way, thank everybody for helpping.

Comment: @Jason Probably the reason, yes ; )

Answer (score 20):

Easiest example

```
python -c "print 'example'"
```

It is useful whenever your program has a single line of code, for example, list comprehensions, etc.

Another example can be

```
python -c "a='example';print a"
```

As you can see, multiple statements are separated by `;`